# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException - running DAO project

Tags: java, mysql, sql, intellij-idea, runtime-error

I created database and two tables for easy DAO program. DB is Mysql, and for creation I used terminal. Here is creation code for two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(40),
    course INT,
    email VARCHAR(40),
    department_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(department_id) REFERENCES departments(department_id)
);

CREATE TABLE departments (
    department_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(department_id)
);
```

I used for IDE Intellij. it has smart DB support.

You can see, ***how does it look***:

[image: looking]

But when I run my code I saw next ***bunch of exceptions***:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`University`.`students`, CONSTRAINT `students_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `departments` (`department_id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
    at lab.epam.controller.dao.StudentDAO.save(StudentDAO.java:82)
    at lab.epam.DAOMain.main(DAOMain.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Here is my ***main()***:

```
public class DAOMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentDAO studentDAO = new StudentDAO();
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(9);
        student.setName("Test");
        student.setCourse(5);
        student.setEmail("student.name@dot.com");
        student.setDepartmentId(16);
        studentDAO.save(student);
        System.out.println(studentDAO.getById(9));
        studentDAO.deleteById(9);
        System.out.println(new DepartmentDAO().getById(12));
    }
```

Why does this exception happen?

I couldn't figure out what I missed here.

**UPDATE:**

Here is [POJO](http://pastebin.com/ABa45Gf7).

I fixed some points but it keep working not exactly I want.

Here is fixed output:

> Student { id=9, name='super student', course=5, email='super.student@dot.com', department=null, departmentId=14}

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Share your POJO files please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is coming because of Foreign Key reference. When you are trying to insert in Student table with department_id value, MySQL is checking that if a row in Department table is present with same ID or not. If not you get MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.

Please check Department table and you wont find a row with id 16.

Since you are using DAO, you should save Department first and then Student to solve this issue.

Looking at your POJO, in Department POJO column name is not same as table column name.

Another thing is when you are calling Student save, how department object is getting saved?

I am new to DAO, so I might be missing something here.

Answer (score -1):

The what the ConstraintViolatedException means that you're inserting a record into a table which references a second value which isn't present.

In your table students you have department_id as a foreign key, but are trying to insert a record into students before the departments table contains the value referenced in the students table when you write:

student.setDepartmentId(16);

Insert a record into departments for the new department before inserting a record into students which contains the department id required.